# Can a monitor be run in portrait mode with full screen games?

Tags: display, portrait

I don't have a rotatable monitor at present to try this with.  In the past I've seen some, they work fine so long as you have the normal desktop up.  Unfortunately, they cease to rotate the image when you go full screen for a game or the like.

Is there any solution to allow this?  And are there any other gotchas I should be aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends primarily on the resolutions that the game supports - there's no particular technical limitation of portrait mode over landscape that would make it impossible, but I think you'll find that many games won't let you choose appropriate resolutions, or if they do they'll look terrible.  (I haven't seen a video driver in a long time that would unrotate on fullscreening, so that's probably not a concern.)

Comment: So you're saying the rotation problem was just a video driver issue and not inherent?

Comment: That would be my assumption, yes.